# is function with two varibles differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a function $$z=|x-4|+|y-2|$$

I would like to ask you, wheter the function is in these points $z(4,y)$ and $z(x,2)$ differentiable. If not, how would you call this - sharp edges?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=|x-4|+|y-2|$ It is not differentiable since the partial differential 
${{\partial f}\over{\partial x}}(4,2)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think you meant the partial derivative not existing at $(4,2)$?

Answer (score 0):

For function to be differentiable first you need to check if both partial derivatives exists or not. If they exists then you just need to prove they are continuous. As explained above the fx does not exist at point(4,2) that's why we can conclude the function is not differentiable